# How to use react-routers in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new in Reactjs and I want to use router but not working,displaying blank page.

How can I use router Home category and products.I put code in App.jsx and index.jsx but showing me blank page,how can I resolve this.

Following is my App.jsx code

```
/* Import statements */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

/* Home component */
const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
)

/* Category component */
const Category = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Category</h2>
  </div>
)

/* Products component */
const Products = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Products</h2>
  </div>
)

/* App component */
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-light">
          <ul className="nav navbar-nav">

           /* Link components are used for linking to other views */
            <li><Link to="/">Homes</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/category">Category</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/products">Products</Link></li>

          </ul>
         </nav>

          /* Route components are rendered if the path prop matches the current URL */
           <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
           <Route path="/category" component={Category}/>
           <Route path="/products" component={Products}/>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is my index.jsx code

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import { App } from './components/App';
import './style.less';

render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import a BrowserRouter and wrap the whole app code into that component for routes can react to url changes, so in your import `react-router-dom`

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from “react-router-dom”

return (
   <BrowserRouter>
   <div>
    <nav className="navbar navbar-light">
      <ul className="nav navbar-nav">

       /* Link components are used for linking to other views */
        <li><Link to="/">Homes</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/category">Category</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/products">Products</Link></li>

      </ul>
     </nav>

      /* Route components are rendered if the path prop matches the current URL */
       <Switch>
       <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
       <Route path="/category" component={Category}/>
       <Route path="/products" component={Products}/>
       </Switch>

  </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```

Doing that you will get a working example, so  `BrowserRouter` will listen for changes done into url and react that changes into its `Route` components, remember you should need pass to each`Route` component a property called `exact={true}` or even better wrap all your `Route` components with `Switch` component, that prevent to display all Route when a change url is done, with `Switch` will render only the route that matches with the exact path